# Performance of bulk access vs single access in Hazelcast IMDG

Tags: caching, hazelcast

We use IMDG locally as an in-process library, mainly for caching in maps.

Traditionally we accessed the elements in the map using single value access, invoking javax.cache.Cache#get, however we have an agenda of moving to a bulk access, using javax.cache.Cache#getAll. However when testing the bulk access performance-wise we found that statistically it works slower than looping over the keys and accessing one by one, which is quite surprising to say the least. I would expect to see at least a modest improvement in performance. Over the course of 4 hours of continuous execution of our code, the total access time to Hazelcast maps via bulk API was roughly 50% slower than single access to the same keys. I wonder how this can be explained.

We use version 3.2.15. I wonder if it makes sense to upgrade to 4.x.x and check there.
Thanks!

Comment: Worse performance from getAll seems unexpected. What is the size of the key set you request and the expected data size? One thing to consider is that getAll has increased memory requirements vs getting single entries one by one, so GC overhead may be the culprit. Have you been monitoring GC during your test?

Comment: The size varies with each request, the range being 1 to roughly 100 entries, and the entries don't take a lot of space so I don't think the GC is playing a considerable role. Is it possible it's related to near cache somehow? Could it be the single request will go to the near cache first and potentially find the values there while the bulk will always go to network? Thanks.

Comment: Is the process that makes the _get_ and _getAll_ calls a Hazelcast client or a Hazelcast server ? Your wording on the original question suggests the latter, but near-cache is available for JCache on the former.

Comment: If it's a client, _getAll_ checks the near-cache - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/cache/impl/nearcache/NearCachedClientCacheProxy.java#L362

Comment: If you do have a near-cache, perhaps see if the performance is the same if you turn it off? If you have a near-cache, a _get_ means at most one cache miss, at most one entry to retrieve from remote, and so at most one entry to store in the near-cache. However, a _getAll_ means potentally retrieving more from remote and these must be stored locally, potentially taking the near-cache over any size limit.

Comment: @NeilStevenson we use in-process IMDG, specifically this test was performed on a cluster of 2 nodes of our product with means also 2 nodes of IMDG. My understanding is that near cache makes sense in a cluster environment regardless whether it's in-process or client/server IMDG, because there's always a chance the node that makes request doesn't contain the value in its partition, am I right? Also I don't quite get your second comment, if I get 10 values in bulk vs 10 values in single reads in a loop and I use near cache, won't near cache have the same data eventually? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so if you use embedded near-cache doesn't apply. Are you able to share code that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: My second question isn't really relevant now, but for completeness:  Once running, you would expect the near-cache to be full. A `get` could need to add 1 item, so the least useful item needs identified and removed to make space. A `getAll` could need to add 100 items, so 100 others need identified for removal, the same amount of work, but all at once.

Comment: @NeilStevenson I'm confused about the near cache now. I started debugging inside the Hazelcast and I DO see that the near cache is accessed in embedded mode. I see that com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.NearCachedMapProxyImpl#getAllInternal is invoked during the bulk access and it tries to populate the result from the near cache.
It would be quite difficult to share the code for me, it's part of the product and I will need a lot of effort to extract it.

Comment: That's interesting. `om.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.NearCachedMapProxyImpl` is for an IMap. But I would expect `javax.cache.Cache` to operate on an ICache (`com.hazelcast.cache.impl.CacheProxy`). It doesn't change much here though, bulk get shoulld be faster than individual get,

Comment: Are you able to turn near-cache off and see it is the problem or is unrelated ? How do you have the IMap configured ? (backup-count=1 ? read-from-backup==false?) ? If upgrading isn't too difficult, that's also worth a try, and it'll help to know whether this changes behaviour or not.

Comment: Thanks @NeilStevenson, I'll try some of your suggestions.